# Splitting wordpress menu without editing css

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress menu with 6 items,
I need to spit the menu into two,3 items in the left div and 3 in the right div.
The style is given for the div class ,so in my case giving style to menu item doesn't work(either by adding class or by menu item id).Is there any other way to split my menu into two.Anything to do with this code?

```
           <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: why don't you use two or three different menus ???

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What about adding !important to the added style?